# How to count records generated by following query?

Tags: mysql, join, count

How can I get the total count of records generated by following query?

```
SELECT
AccountA.Name AS 'Account_Name',
AccountA.Industry AS 'Account_Industry',
AccountA.Key_Account__c AS 'Key_Account',
UserA.Name AS 'Account_Owner',
UserA.Sales_Team__c AS 'Account_Owner_Sales_Team',
Opportunity.Opportunity_Number__c AS 'Opportunity_Number',
RecordType.Name AS 'Opportunity_Record_Type',
Opportunity.Name AS 'Opportunity_Name',
Opportunity.Important_Notes__c AS 'Important_Notes',
UserB.Name AS 'Opportunity_Owner',
UserRole.Name as 'Opportunity_Owner_Role',
Opportunity.LeadSource AS 'Opportunity_Lead_Source',
Pricebook2.Name AS 'Price_Book_2_Name',
CampaignA.Name AS 'Campaign_Name', 
CampaignB.Name AS 'Assigned_Campaign_Name',
AccountC.Name AS 'Primary_Reseller',
AccountD.Name AS 'Primary_Distributor',
Opportunity.StageName AS 'Stage',
Opportunity.Probability AS 'Probability',
Opportunity.CreatedDate AS 'Create_Date',
Opportunity.LastModifiedDate AS 'Last_Modified_Date',
Opportunity.FiscalQuarter AS 'Fiscal_Quarter',
Opportunity.FiscalYear AS 'Fiscal_Year',
Opportunity.Fiscal AS 'Fiscal',
CONCAT('Q', Opportunity.FiscalQuarter,'-',Opportunity.FiscalYear) AS 'Unformatted_Fiscal_Period',
CONCAT(Opportunity.FiscalYear, '-Q', Opportunity.FiscalQuarter) AS 'Fiscal_Period',
CONCAT(YEAR(Opportunity.CloseDate),MONTH(Opportunity.CloseDate)) AS 'Close_Month',
Opportunity.Won_Date__c AS 'Won_Date',
Opportunity.Amount AS Amount,
Opportunity.Roll_Out_Start__c AS Rollout_Start_Date,
Opportunity.Roll_Out_End__c AS Rollout_End_Date,
Opportunity.LastModifiedDate AS Opportunity_Last_Modified_Date,
OpportunityLineItem.Product_Family__c AS 'Product_Family',
OpportunityLineItem.Product_Group__c AS 'Product_Group',
OpportunityLineItem.Product_Name__c AS 'Product_Name',
Product2.PET_Name__c AS 'PET_Name',
FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account AccountA ON Opportunity.AccountId =  AccountA.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountB INNER JOIN User UserA ON AccountB.OwnerId = UserA.Id On Opportunity.AccountId = AccountB.Id
LEFT JOIN RecordType ON Opportunity.RecordTypeId = RecordType.Id
LEFT JOIN User UserB ON Opportunity.OwnerId = UserB.Id
LEFT JOIN User UserC INNER JOIN UserRole ON UserC.UserRoleId = UserRole.Id On Opportunity.OwnerId = UserC.Id
LEFT JOIN Pricebook2 ON Opportunity.Pricebook2Id = Pricebook2.Id
LEFT JOIN Campaign CampaignA ON Opportunity.CampaignId = CampaignA.Id
LEFT JOIN Campaign CampaignB ON Opportunity.AssignedCampaignID__c = CampaignB.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountC ON Opportunity.Primary_Reseller__c =  AccountC.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountD ON Opportunity.Primary_Distributor__c = AccountD.Id
LEFT JOIN OpportunityLineItem JOIN Product2 ON OpportunityLineItem.Product2Id = Product2.Id ON Opportunity.Id = OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId
WHERE (Product2.Product_Category__c IN ('SAB', 'Warranty', '2 Warranty', '3 Warranty') OR RecordType.Name = 'Services')
AND Opportunity.IsDeleted = 0
AND AccountA.Name NOT LIKE '%Dummy%'
AND AccountA.Name NOT IN ('Admin Test Account', 'ABC CORPORATION')
AND OpportunityLineItem.Alternative__c = 0
AND Product2.Name NOT LIKE 'SM-%'
```

Comment: Are you asking how many rows in the result set?  If so, what client are you using?  Or do you want to know now many rows of Opportunity satisfy the filters?

Comment: To give you an example, one specific Opportunity.Opportunity_Number__c has 17 OpportunityLineItem.Product_Name__c so I see 17 rows with different product names. What I am trying to find out is like these 17 how many records are showed.

Comment: Are you familiar with `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @RickJames I was familiar with Count(*) but didn't know the position to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN MSSQL Server

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 

(
SELECT
AccountA.Name AS 'Account_Name',
AccountA.Industry AS 'Account_Industry',
AccountA.Key_Account__c AS 'Key_Account',
UserA.Name AS 'Account_Owner',
UserA.Sales_Team__c AS 'Account_Owner_Sales_Team',
Opportunity.Opportunity_Number__c AS 'Opportunity_Number',
RecordType.Name AS 'Opportunity_Record_Type',
Opportunity.Name AS 'Opportunity_Name',
Opportunity.Important_Notes__c AS 'Important_Notes',
UserB.Name AS 'Opportunity_Owner',
UserRole.Name as 'Opportunity_Owner_Role',
Opportunity.LeadSource AS 'Opportunity_Lead_Source',
Pricebook2.Name AS 'Price_Book_2_Name',
CampaignA.Name AS 'Campaign_Name', 
CampaignB.Name AS 'Assigned_Campaign_Name',
AccountC.Name AS 'Primary_Reseller',
AccountD.Name AS 'Primary_Distributor',
Opportunity.StageName AS 'Stage',
Opportunity.Probability AS 'Probability',
Opportunity.CreatedDate AS 'Create_Date',
Opportunity.LastModifiedDate AS 'Last_Modified_Date',
Opportunity.FiscalQuarter AS 'Fiscal_Quarter',
Opportunity.FiscalYear AS 'Fiscal_Year',
Opportunity.Fiscal AS 'Fiscal',
CONCAT('Q', Opportunity.FiscalQuarter,'-',Opportunity.FiscalYear) AS 'Unformatted_Fiscal_Period',
CONCAT(Opportunity.FiscalYear, '-Q', Opportunity.FiscalQuarter) AS 'Fiscal_Period',
CONCAT(YEAR(Opportunity.CloseDate),MONTH(Opportunity.CloseDate)) AS 'Close_Month',
Opportunity.Won_Date__c AS 'Won_Date',
Opportunity.Amount AS Amount,
Opportunity.Roll_Out_Start__c AS Rollout_Start_Date,
Opportunity.Roll_Out_End__c AS Rollout_End_Date,
Opportunity.LastModifiedDate AS Opportunity_Last_Modified_Date,
OpportunityLineItem.Product_Family__c AS 'Product_Family',
OpportunityLineItem.Product_Group__c AS 'Product_Group',
OpportunityLineItem.Product_Name__c AS 'Product_Name',
Product2.PET_Name__c AS 'PET_Name',
FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account AccountA ON Opportunity.AccountId =  AccountA.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountB INNER JOIN User UserA ON AccountB.OwnerId = UserA.Id On Opportunity.AccountId = AccountB.Id
LEFT JOIN RecordType ON Opportunity.RecordTypeId = RecordType.Id
LEFT JOIN User UserB ON Opportunity.OwnerId = UserB.Id
LEFT JOIN User UserC INNER JOIN UserRole ON UserC.UserRoleId = UserRole.Id On Opportunity.OwnerId = UserC.Id
LEFT JOIN Pricebook2 ON Opportunity.Pricebook2Id = Pricebook2.Id
LEFT JOIN Campaign CampaignA ON Opportunity.CampaignId = CampaignA.Id
LEFT JOIN Campaign CampaignB ON Opportunity.AssignedCampaignID__c = CampaignB.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountC ON Opportunity.Primary_Reseller__c =  AccountC.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountD ON Opportunity.Primary_Distributor__c = AccountD.Id
LEFT JOIN OpportunityLineItem JOIN Product2 ON OpportunityLineItem.Product2Id = Product2.Id ON Opportunity.Id = OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId
WHERE (Product2.Product_Category__c IN ('SAB', 'Warranty', '2 Warranty', '3 Warranty') OR RecordType.Name = 'Services')
AND Opportunity.IsDeleted = 0
AND AccountA.Name NOT LIKE '%Dummy%'
AND AccountA.Name NOT IN ('Admin Test Account', 'ABC CORPORATION')
AND OpportunityLineItem.Alternative__c = 0
AND Product2.Name NOT LIKE 'SM-%'

)a
```

Comment: In general, any standard SQL database can do this.

Comment: You may want to explain what you're doing here to make it easier for the OP to follow

Comment: By a lucky coincidence both DBMS (SQL Server and MySQL) allow this non-standard quoting of identifiers: `AS 'Account_Name'` ... Please, don't use this. The standard is `AS "Account_Name"` if you really need to quote an identifier. SQL Server also allows/prefers square brackets `AS [Account_Name]` and MySQL allows/prefers backquotes `AS \`Account_Name\``

Comment: Suggest you replace all the columns with simply `COUNT(*)`.  Then get rid of the outer `SELECT`.